# Trying to make posts on Wordpress using Java but the title won't show up

Tags: java, wordpress

I'm trying to make a post on Wordpress using an API. So far I have this code and I can make posts but the only thing that is being published is the content of the post and not the title. KI can show the category, but not the title. What am I missing? This is the code I have so far:

```
public void connessione(){
        try {

            URL url = new URL(Costanti.URL_POST);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + Costanti.BEARER_TOKEN);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());

            wr.append(this.creaPost());
            wr.flush();
            urlConnection.connect();            
            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(); 
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 


    }

    private String creaPost(){
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s.append("?");
        s.append("title=").append("Title");
        s.append("&content=").append("description");
        s.append("&status=").append("publish");       

        return s.toString();
    }
```

I wanted to send the data as a request body and not as request parameters but I don't know how to do that. 
I also wanted to try to use something like JSON libraries to write the code as JSON instead of java string but NetBeans won't read the libraries for some reason and I don't know how to fix that either.

Also this is the JSON I have as a response from that method:

```
{
    "id": 73,
    "date": "2019-11-10T10:09:55",
    "date_gmt": "2019-11-10T10:09:55",
    "guid": {
        "rendered": "http://localhost/tesi/2019/11/10/73/",
        "raw": "http://localhost/tesi/2019/11/10/73/"
    },
    "modified": "2019-11-10T10:09:55",
    "modified_gmt": "2019-11-10T10:09:55",
    "password": "",
    "slug": "73",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "post",
    "link": "http://localhost/tesi/2019/11/10/73/",
    "title": {
        "raw": "",
        "rendered": ""
    },
    "content": {
        "raw": "description",
        "rendered": "<p>description</p>\n",
        "protected": false,
        "block_version": 0
    },
    "excerpt": {
        "raw": "",
        "rendered": "<p>descrizione</p>\n",
        "protected": false
    },
    "author": 1,
    "featured_media": 0,
    "comment_status": "open",
    "ping_status": "open",
    "sticky": false,
    "template": "",
    "format": "standard",
    "meta": [],
    "categories": [
        1
    ],
    "tags": [],
    "permalink_template": "http://localhost/tesi/2019/11/10/%postname%/",
    "generated_slug": "73",
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/tesi/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/73"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/tesi/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
            }
        ],
        "about": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/tesi/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post"
            }
        ],
        "author": [
            {
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "http://localhost/tesi/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1"
            }
        ],
        "replies": [
            {
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "http://localhost/tesi/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=73"
            }
        ],
        "version-history": [
            {
                "count": 0,
                "href": "http://localhost/tesi/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/73/revisions"
            }
        ],
        "wp:attachment": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/tesi/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=73"
            }
        ],
        "wp:term": [
            {
                "taxonomy": "category",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "http://localhost/tesi/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?post=73"
            },
            {
                "taxonomy": "post_tag",
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "http://localhost/tesi/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=73"
            }
        ],
        "wp:action-publish": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/tesi/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/73"
            }
        ],
        "wp:action-unfiltered-html": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/tesi/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/73"
            }
        ],
        "wp:action-sticky": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/tesi/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/73"
            }
        ],
        "wp:action-assign-author": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/tesi/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/73"
            }
        ],
        "wp:action-create-categories": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/tesi/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/73"
            }
        ],
        "wp:action-assign-categories": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/tesi/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/73"
            }
        ],
        "wp:action-create-tags": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/tesi/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/73"
            }
        ],
        "wp:action-assign-tags": [
            {
                "href": "http://localhost/tesi/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/73"
            }
        ],
        "curies": [
            {
                "name": "wp",
                "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
                "templated": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it but putting **&** before 'title='
so now it's like this:

```
private String creaPost(){
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    s.append("?");
    s.append("&title=").append("Title");
    s.append("&content=").append("description");
    s.append("&status=").append("publish");       

    return s.toString();
}
```

and it works fine